# Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type 'DbSet<>'. Ambiguous call to 'Where'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1.2 and I get the following errors

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task<List<Client>> GetClients()
{
      return await (from client in context.Client
                    select client).ToListAsync();
}
```

> Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type 'DbSet<>'. Ambiguous call to 'Where'
> Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type 'DbSet<>'. Ambiguous call to 'Select'

I get ambiguous invocation:

> System.Collections.Generic
> System.Collections.Generic
> System.Collections.Generic

I don't have any methods that override the above.

Comment: what do you mean too much using?

Comment: please show minimal code for this (with used libraries)

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: as I wrote ... too much `using` use either `using System.Linq;` or `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` because both namespaces define extensions

Comment: can't there are other functions that use MicrosoftEntityFramework in this file like ```ExecuteSqlCommandAsync```

Comment: then use extension directly ... like `Namespace.ExtensionsClass.Select(dbset, item=>new { .... })`

Comment: how would you add it in my code. can you show please?

Comment: easy google search leads here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18124

Comment: The workaround there solves the problem with the where but not the select

Comment: Workaround of the above is to add AsQuerable() to the DbSet

Answer (score 1):

According to this github thread: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18124

The current workaround is to call `AsQueryable()` on your DBSet. Eg:

`_context.YourDbSet.AsQueryable()`

Comment: I think this issue was fixed. Not sure in which version of .NET. Think it was fixed in .NET 5